# pgfplots external vs TikZ external

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, externalize

In my preamble I have both

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
```

Since the first one externalizes TikZ figures, while the second one is more aimed towards pgf figures.

But since every PFGPlot is a TikZ figure, it seems to me that the second external in the preamble is obsolete. Is this a wrong conclusion? (e.g. does PGF external also take care of axes).

> **Question short form**: Is it obsolete to use PGF external if TikZ external is already used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This quote from section 5.6 *Image externalization* of the `pgfplots` manual probably answers your question:

> The external library has been written by Christian Feuersänger
>   (author of `pgfplots`). It has been contributed to TikZ as general
>   purpose library, so the reference documentation along with all tweaks
>   can be found in [7, Section “Externalization Library”]. The command
>   `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` is actually just a wrapper which loads
>   `\usetikzlibrary{external}` or, if this library does not yet exist
>   because the installed `pgf` has at most version 2.00, it will load a
>   copy which is shipped with `pgfplots`.

(7 is a reference to the manual for TikZ/`pgf`.)

So yes, given that the two are identical, having one is enough.

## Small correction

Stefan Pinnow mentions in a comment that because `pgfplots` has a faster release cycle than TikZ, the version of the library that ships with `pgfplots` (as per the quote above) is in fact newer, with more bugs fixed, than that in TikZ.

For this reason it would be best to use

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
```

or

```
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}
```

Comment: As Torbjørn already stated: In principal it is enough to load just *one* of the two libraries. But because TikZ has last been updated "a long time ago" the `external` library shipped with PGFPlots is "much newer" and has some bugs fixed. So I recommend using `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` or `\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}` which both load the `external` library of PGFPlots.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks! I added a note on that to my answer.